# When is a matrix similar to a skew symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

More precisely. Is there any way one can tell if a matrix is similar to a skew symmetric matrix by looking at its eigenvalues or even better at the coefficients of its characteristic polynomial ? For instance, if a  $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$  is similar to a skew symmetric matrix $S$( that is $A=U^{-1}SU$ ) then $$ tr(A)=0, $$ and $$ tr(A^2)=-2 det(A).$$ These two conditions are necessary but not sufficient. Are there any sufficient conditions?

Answer (score 5):

$A$ is similar to a skew symmetric matrix if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable with purely imaginary eigenvalues.

Here's a different way to put that: $A$ is similar to a skew symmetric matrix if and only if there exist distinct positive numbers $r_1,\dots,r_k$ such that
$$
A
\left( A^2 + r_1I \right)
\left( A^2 + r_2I \right) \cdots
\left( A^2 + r_kI \right) = 0
$$
Any set of values $r_1,\dots,r_k$ gives us a sufficient condition, then.

Comment: Omno , I think that there is a little mistake about the second equivalence. The condition seems (to me) to be: $A\Pi_j(A^2+r_jI_n)=0$ where the $r_j$ are distinct $>0$. Note that $A^2=0$ does not imply that $A$ is similar to a skew-symmetric.

Comment: @LoupBlanc excellent catch! Fixed it.